# How to make \Sexpr{} ignore NA

Tags: r, rstudio, sweave

I run into the following issue. I define a Latex command for ifcase to choose from several options. Then I have some r code that determines the numbers used in ifcase via \Sexpr{}. My problem is that when \Sexpr produces NA those also appear in the output file. I hope that the MWE helps to clarify what I mean, otherwise please don't hesitate to ask.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\newcommand{\QPR}[1]
{
\ifcase #1
\or 
         A
\or
         B
\or
         C
\fi
}

<<g, echo=FALSE, results=tex,prefix=FALSE>>=
S=2:3
@

\QPR{\Sexpr{S[1]}}
\QPR{\Sexpr{S[2]}}
\QPR{\Sexpr{S[3]}}

\end{document}
```

The output reads "B C NA" but I only want "B C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `\ifcase` only allows an integer argument, and NA doesn't look like one to LaTeX.  You need to change NA into some integer value that isn't in the list of cases.  For example, this version converts NA to -1, which would never match a case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\newcommand{\QPR}[1]
{
\ifcase #1
\or 
         A
\or
         B
\or
         C
\fi
}

<<g, echo=FALSE, results=tex,prefix=FALSE>>=
S=2:3
hideNA <- function(x) if (is.na(x)) -1 else x
@

\QPR{\Sexpr{hideNA(S[1])}}
\QPR{\Sexpr{hideNA(S[2])}}
\QPR{\Sexpr{hideNA(S[3])}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation. This is far better than the workaround of adding values manually with c(S,99:199) I had come up with.